# Null and alternative distribution of test statistic

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, p-value

This question is based on [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.06545). I am trying to find out whether two samples ($S_p$~$P^n$ and $S_Q$~$Q^m$ ) are drawn from the same distribution. So my $H_0: P=Q$ and $H_1: P \neq Q$. I have also derived a test statistic $t$ to test the above hypothesis. Now in the paper, it is mentioned that the test statistic follows the null distribution $t$~$N(0.5,1/4n)$ and follows the alternative distribution $t$~$N(p,p(1-p)/n)$. Now, from a real-world example, I have calculated $t$, how do I accept or reject the hypothesis, given the two distributions as above?

(Note: This question is another part of a [similar question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/403382/indicator-function-expression-for-two-sample-test) I asked a while ago. I decided to open a new thread as I thought this was a different topic. Apologies if I violated any rules on this forum.)

Comment: First link broken.

Comment: Sorry about that. It's fixed now